# In SQL, how do you count distinct values of a newly created alias with a left statement

Tags: sql

I probably didn't word the title properly, but basically I've created a column and I'm trying to count the distinct values within that column:

```
SELECT
    LEFT (route_id, 7) AS unique_route_plan,
    route_id,
    station_code,
    country_code,
    plan_wave
FROM
    perfectmile_na.d_perfectmile_routing
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND '2020-12-31 00:00:00'
    AND station_code LIKE 'D%'
    AND plan_planning_algo <> 'DYNAMIC-PLANNER'
```

So in the above, I'd like to know how many distinct values of unique_route_plan there are.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you only want 364 days of last years data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the main query in a subquery like this and then do a count of distinct.

```
select count(distinct unique_route_plan) from
(SELECT
    LEFT (route_id, 7) AS unique_route_plan,
    route_id,
    station_code,
    country_code,
    plan_wave
FROM
    perfectmile_na.d_perfectmile_routing
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND '2020-12-31 00:00:00'
    AND station_code LIKE 'D%'
    AND plan_planning_algo <> 'DYNAMIC-PLANNER')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you want your data or provide an example of what you're looking for, however presumably you want a count of the distinct values as a column in the same query, so you can do

```
SELECT
    LEFT (route_id, 7) AS unique_route_plan,
    count(*) over (partition by left(route_id, 7)) as unique_route_plan_count,
    route_id,
    station_code,
    country_code,
    plan_wave
FROM
    perfectmile_na.d_perfectmile_routing
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND '2020-12-31 00:00:00' -- << -- Are you sure??
    AND station_code LIKE 'D%'
    AND plan_planning_algo <> 'DYNAMIC-PLANNER'
```

And note your date range excludes the 31st December - that might be what you intended but I suspect not?

Comment: Great call on the dates, I didn't realize.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct unique_route_plan) from
(
SELECT
    LEFT (route_id, 7) AS unique_route_plan,
    route_id,
    station_code,
    country_code,
    plan_wave
FROM
    perfectmile_na.d_perfectmile_routing
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND '2020-12-31 00:00:00'
    AND station_code LIKE 'D%'
    AND plan_planning_algo <> 'DYNAMIC-PLANNER')t
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(route_id, 7)) AS num_unique_route_plan
FROM perfectmile_na.d_perfectmile_routing
WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND
      station_code LIKE 'D%' AND
      plan_planning_algo <> 'DYNAMIC-PLANNER';
```

Note:  If you want all of 2020, the logic would be:

```
WHERE date >= '2020-01-01' AND
      date < '2021-01-01' AND
      station_code LIKE 'D%' AND
      plan_planning_algo <> 'DYNAMIC-PLANNER';
```

I would advise you not to use `BETWEEN` on dates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on dates!  I appreciate your help!